# How set a 'timer' before running body from if/else statement?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, timer

In android studio, I want to set some kind of 'timer' before the `if/else` statement runs parts of it's body. In this case the `edit1.setText("")` and `edit1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFF"));` Is there a way to do this.

Thanks in advance, have a nice day!

EDIT: I'm not using any UI libraries.

```
public void check1(View view) {
    uinput = edit1.getText().toString();
    if (uinput.equals(answerList[0])) {
        edit1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
        score++;
        score_view.setText(String.valueOf(score));

        // I only want to delay the three below.

        view1.setText(questionList[1]);
        edit1.setText("");
        edit1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    } else {
        edit1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        wrong++;
        wrong_view.setText(String.valueOf(wrong));

        // I only want to delay the three below.

        view1.setText(questionList[1]);
        edit1.setText("");
        edit1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFF"));
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is Swing, you'll probably want to use Swing Timers to execute this.

Comment: You say you're not using any UI libraries, but you're using methods and classes that suggests you're using Swing. Is that not the case?

Comment: If I understand right I need to declare a library? If so I'm not using swing or anything else.

Comment: What is `View` from?

Comment: view is a `TextView`. And the  View in the method is from `onClick`.

Comment: Is this Android development?

Comment: Yes it is. Forgot to mention sorry.

Comment: That's an important detail. Please update the question with that information. And you may be able to use [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer).